# custom table display - help turning static html to dynamic php

Tags: component, javascript, jquery, database, custom-component

I am trying to modify the list view of my Joomla component to display my table's data in a more user-friendly fashion. It currently simply displays all data in a regular table with columns and rows, like such:
[image: Current database list view]

But I want the data to display partly in the title, partly in a drop-down menu. I have made an example of the format I am shooting for on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn71Lh5v/7/).

The thing is, I am new to PHP and I am not sure how to turn my static HTML code into dynamic PHP code. I want each row to display its data with an independently-functioning dropdown menu (the click events are currently linked together). What's more, I want each row to have its own "indicator light" which shows how full each classroom is based on that row's own *cap* and *att* values.

If I could see some example code, it would be very helpful. I need to dynamically fill each session menu and dynamically change the status indicator using javascript. It's just too big of a next step to wrap my mind around all at once.

I assume I need to put my rows in a list format, fill the list out dynamically using PHP, and then somehow iterate through a loop in my javascript, calling the *att*/ *cap* values for each row and modifying the respective css values for *ul .sessions li:nth-child(x).css('background','red');*

Here is the code for my current table display, in case it is helpful:

```
    <table class="table table-striped" id="sessionList">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->state)): ?>
                <th width="5%">
    <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'JPUBLISHED', 'a.state', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
</th>
            <?php endif; ?>

                            <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_ID', 'a.id', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_DATE', 'a.date', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_TIME', 'a.time', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_TITLE', 'a.title', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_TEACHER', 'a.teacher', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_LVL', 'a.lvl', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_NOTES', 'a.notes', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_JR', 'a.jr', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_CAP', 'a.cap', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_ATT', 'a.att', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>
                <th class=''>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_SID', 'a.sid', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                </th>


                            <?php if ($canEdit || $canDelete): ?>
                    <th class="center">
                <?php echo JText::_('COM_MERAKIAC_SESSIONS_ACTIONS'); ?>
                </th>
                <?php endif; ?>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="<?php echo isset($this->items[0]) ? count(get_object_vars($this->items[0])) : 10; ?>">
                <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
            <?php $canEdit = $user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_merakiac'); ?>

                            <?php if (!$canEdit && $user->authorise('core.edit.own', 'com_merakiac')): ?>
                    <?php $canEdit = JFactory::getUser()->id == $item->created_by; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?>">

                <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->state)) : ?>
                    <?php $class = ($canChange) ? 'active' : 'disabled'; ?>
                    <td class="center">
    <a class="btn btn-micro <?php echo $class; ?>" href="<?php echo ($canChange) ? JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_merakiac&task=session.publish&id=' . $item->id . '&state=' . (($item->state + 1) % 2), false, 2) : '#'; ?>">
    <?php if ($item->state == 1): ?>
        <i class="icon-publish"></i>
    <?php else: ?>
        <i class="icon-unpublish"></i>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
</td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->id; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->date; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php if (isset($item->checked_out) && $item->checked_out) : ?>
                    <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.checkedout', $i, $item->uEditor, $item->checked_out_time, 'sessions.', $canCheckin); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_merakiac&view=session&id='.(int) $item->id); ?>">
                <?php echo $this->escape($item->time); ?></a>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->teacher; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->lvl; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->notes; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->jr; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->cap; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->att; ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $item->sid; ?>
                </td>


                                <?php if ($canEdit || $canDelete): ?>
                    <td class="center">
                        <?php if ($canEdit): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_merakiac&task=sessionform.edit&id=' . $item->id, false, 2); ?>" class="btn btn-mini" type="button"><i class="icon-edit" ></i></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($canDelete): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_merakiac&task=sessionform.remove&id=' . $item->id, false, 2); ?>" class="btn btn-mini delete-button" type="button"><i class="icon-trash" ></i></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For individual operation of the dropdowns you can assign a single class to the dropdown to act as the element trigger, then assign an ID to each dropdown and use $(this) as the event target.

Comment: Take a look at this quick adjustment to your fiddle. It will show you what I am referring to about the dropdowns opening individually. You can use the value of $i in your foreach as the unique ID for each generated set of data. https://jsfiddle.net/wn71Lh5v/14/

Comment: I modified your code here https://jsfiddle.net/wn71Lh5v/15/ as I want the dropdown to trigger on the dropbtn click and not text click. Can you help me with implementing the $i variable in my foreach loop? Here is the foreach loop I wrote, but when rendered, the id simply remains '$i' and doesn't generate a unique value: https://jsfiddle.net/m74n77ot/1/ What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You weren't echoing the value of $i in your new fiddle example. Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/m74n77ot/2/

Comment: Oh and just as an FYI, if you are using the dropbtn class on a div, you can get rid of the <A> tag around your open / close text. It is pointless to have if the div is the trigger and not an href.

Comment: If this works let me know and I will provide an answer so you can mark it as accepted and help keep the JSE clear of unanswered questions.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I got the indicator lights and the dropdowns to operate independently. Regarding the <a> tag, I am only using it to stylize the text on the dropdown button {color:white; margin-left:7px} but it does show up in Joomla as a link, which I don't want. Is there a better way to stylize text in a div where the text is changed with jquery? Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. You can use a span tag around your text and stylize the span with CSS instead of a hyperlink. Then just replace the span text with your jquery. Or you can use a link, either way works. If you use a link you will need your jquery click function to return false so that the default behavior of the link does not affect your URL when clicked. I will add an answer below for you to accept so we can help keep the JSE clean from unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery function was operating against all elements with the assigned target class. The result of that was all dropdowns opening simultaneously. The resolution was to assign a unique ID to each of the dropdown elements and use the jQuery function to open the targets assigned ID using $(this). Example of the jQuery code for the dropdown below.

```
//PHP LOOP FOR EACH ITEM
<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
<div class="topb">
   <div class="sessind"></div>
   <div class="fll"><?php echo $item->time; ?></div>
   <div class="fll"><?php echo $item->title; ?></div>
   <div class="dropbtn" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><a>open</a></div>
</div>
<div class="moredta" id="data_<?php echo $i; ?>">
   <div class="leftc">
      <p><b>teacher:</b> <?php echo $item->teacher; ?></p></div>
   <div class="rightc">
      <p><b>level:</b> <?php echo $item->lvl; ?></p></div>
   <div class="notes">
      <p><b>notes:</b> <?php echo $item->notes; ?></p></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is the jQuery function for manipulating the element via a class declaration and unique ID

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropbtn").on("click",function(e){
            var dataid = $(this).data("id");
        $(this).text(function(i, text){
          return text === "open" ? "close" : "open";
        })
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $("#data_"+dataid).slideToggle('fast');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    var att = 4,
        cap = 5;
    if(att === cap){
        $(".sessind").css('background','red'),
        $(".dropbtn").off("click"),
        $(".dropbtn a").text("full");
    }else if(att >= cap - 2 && att != cap){
        $(".sessind").css('background','yellow');
    }else if(att < cap - 2){
        $(".sessind").css('background','lime');
    }
});
```

The  tag can also be replaced with a span tag in the dropbtn  so it can be styled with CSS. If the href gets replaces with a span you can remove the e.preventDefault() line from the click function.

Glad my answer helped you figure everything out.